# error code C2676 binary '==': 'std::pair<std::string,int>'does not define this operator or a conversion to a type acceptable to the predefined operato

Tags: c++

Does anyone know why the following code doesn't work?
the error occurs because of the code `auto it = find(output.begin(), output.end(), resource);`

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <utility>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    vector<pair<string, int> >output;
    string resource;
    int quantity;
    bool first = true;
    while (true)
    {
        cin >> resource;
        if (resource == "stop")
            break;
        cin >> quantity;
        if (first)
        {
            first = false;
            output.push_back(pair<string, int>(resource, quantity));
            continue;
        }
        auto it = find(output.begin(), output.end(), resource);
        if (it != output.end())
            it->second += quantity;
        else
            output.push_back(pair<string, int>(resource, quantity));
    }

    for (size_t i = 0;i<output.size();i++)
    {
        cout << output[i].first << " -> " << output[i].second << endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Why does this happend and how to fix it?

Comment: You need a bit more smarts, a custom comparison function, to compare a `string` with a `pair` that happens to contain  a `string`.

Comment: *"the error occurs because of the code -> auto it = find(output.begin(), output.end(), resource);"* -- You've narrowed down the problem to a particular line; this is good. Next step: narrow down your code to barely more than this line. The goal of a [mre] is to reproduce the issue. Don't worry about your intended functionality -- a program that does not compile has no functionality. Focus on that one line and just enough in the way of definitions so that every symbol in that line is defined. As long as your error is the first reported by the compiler, you've got "reproducible" covered.

Answer (score 3):

The problem is this statement

```
auto it = find(output.begin(), output.end(), resource);
```

the algorithm `std::find` uses objects of the type `std::pair<std::string, int>` (according to the definition of the vector `output` to which it is applied) to compare them with the object `resource` or the type `std::string` and there is no such an equality operator for objects of these types.

Instead use the `std::find_if` algorithm For example

```
auto it = find_if( output.begin(), output.end(), 
                   [&]( const auto &p ) { return p.first == resource; } );
```

Also instead of the container `std::vector<std::string, int>` consider  using containers `std::map<std::string, int>` or `std::unordered_map<std::string, int>`.

Pay attention to that actually this if statement

```
    if (first)
    {
        first = false;
        output.push_back(pair<string, int>(resource, quantity));
        continue;
    }
```

is redundant. You could at once use this code snippet without the above if statement

```
    auto it = find(output.begin(), output.end(), resource);
    if (it != output.end())
        it->second += quantity;
    else
        output.push_back(pair<string, int>(resource, quantity));
```

provided that you will call the algorithm `std::find_if` as shown in the beginning of the answer.

Comment: honestly, `find_if` with a lambda is less easy to read and not shorter than `for(const auto& element : output) { if (element.first == ressource) { element.second += quantity; break; } }` (and I'd assume what they actually want would be using an `unordered_map` anyways). still, +1 is warranted

Comment: @MarcusMüller It would be worse instead of using one statement.

Comment: you're defining a closure that has a capture expression in that "one statement"; that's not "easy" to grasp, I bet, for a beginner!

Comment: @MarcusMüller It is a very good idea for beginners to learn lambdas. Moreover he already uses the algorithm std::find. So now he will find an application of using std::find_if.

Answer (score 0):

You're looking for a `string` in a vector of `pair`s.

That doesn't work; `find` needs to be able to compare the elements of the thing it's looking in (i.e., `pair<string, int>`) with what you're looking for.

You're using the wrong container type, anyways. You clearly want to store key-value pairs, with the keys being `string`s, and the values `int`s. So, use a map.

```cpp
#include <unordered_map>
…
std::map<std::string, int> output;
…
// if the resource is not yet in the map, accessing it using  [] will create it,
// and assign the default value for an int, 0, to it.
int& value = output[ressource];
value += quantity;
```

A `std::map` or `std::unordered_map` does what you do: it contains pairs of keys and values, but it's way cleverer organized than your vector; you don't have to walk through all the map to find out whether an element is in there.